# usage of ! -d in a if condition

Tags: bash, shell

When reading the bash script for hadoop management, I found the following one

```
if [ ! -d "${HADOOP_HOME}" ]; then
   if [ -d "${CDH_HADOOP_HOME}" ]; then
```

what does `! -d "${HADOOP_HOME}"` and `-d  "${CDH_HADOOP_HOME}`stand for?

Comment: `man test` gives `-d FILE: FILE exists and is a directory` and `! EXPRESSION: EXPRESSION is false`

Answer (score 6):

It's a [file test operator](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).  `-d /some/path` means "return true if /some/path is a directory".  `!` is negation, so `! -d /some/path` means "return true if /some/path is *not* a directory".